# Duda con formulario dinamico en html

Tags: php, html, sql

Tengo un proyecto web donde entre las multiples funciones se encuentra una de añadir alumnos a una base de datos SQL:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el campo de colegios, tengo una lista de "seleccion multiple":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo es (obviando la etiqueta form)(HTML):

```html
<label for="name">Colegio</label>
                <select name="colegio">
                    <option value="..">-- Elija --</option>
                    <option value="San Antonio">Liceo San Antonio</option>
                    <option value="Altazor">Colegio Altazor</option>
                    <option value="Ruben Castro">Colegio Ruben Castro</option>
                    <option value="San Patricio">Colegio San Patricio</option>
                    <option value="SEK">SEK</option>
                </select>
```

Sin embargo, la base de datos respecto a la informacion a colegios es cambiante (se añaden/elminan colegios constante), debido a la naturaleza del codigo, cada vez que esto pasa, el formulario tiene que ser cambiado a mano.

¿Es posible automatizar esto?
Es decir, que el listado sea dinamico, que al hacer un cambio en la base de datos, se pueda cambiar tambien el listado.

Comment: Si se puede, solo tienes que generar las opciones del select con el resultado de una consulta pidiendo los nombres existentes.

Comment: ¿En vez de una lista de opciones un text que asegure que el nombre es el correcto dices?

De hecho hice eso como un "parche" para que mi profesor no me regañe

Comment: Tienes que hacer una consulta a la base de datos, al tener ese objeto disponible en la vista tienes que recorrerlo para que cada uno te genere un option.

Comment: Debes crear una tabla una tabla en la base de datos con los colegios, y después hacer una consulta a esta tabla para traer todos los registros. Seguidamente haces un ciclo para recorrer los colegios y desplegar las opciones del select.